# Is conditional entropy ever taken to be a random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, information-theory, conditional-expectation, entropy

In probability theory, the conditional expectation $E(X|Y)$ and variance $V(X|Y)$ er usually taken to be random variables, st. the value of $E(X|Y)$ depends on what value $Y$ ends up taking.

I've just started learning information theory, but I get the impression that conditionals are usually "averaged out", st. $H(X|Y)$ really means $EH(X|Y)$. I suppose because it just turns out more practical that way.

Is that a correct distinction to make? Are there ever examples in information theory where the conditional entropy (or divergence etc.) is taken to be a random variable and not "averaged out"?

Answer (score 4):

Actually $H(X|Y=Y)$ is a random variable, and $H(X|Y=y)$ is a number, namely, the entropy of the conditional distribution $p_{X|Y=y}$. In older textbooks you see the more accurate notation

$$ EH(X|Y) = \sum_y p_Y(y)H(X|Y=y)$$

which means that the conditional entropy is an expectation over the random variable $H(X|Y=Y)$. In newer textbooks this is now abbreviated as $H(X|Y)$.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a quick look at the definition of the conditional entropy, given by, 
$$H(X|Y ) = \sum_{y } p(y)H(X|Y = y),$$ 
we can say that $H(X|Y = y)$ is a random variable, but $H(X|Y)$ is a constant. 
Note that $H(X|Y)$ is the expected value of $H(X|Y = y)$ over $y$.

Comment: Yes, what I wonder about is if there are any cases in which it makes sense to use it as a random variable, similar to conditional expectation? And if there is an intuitive reason why this is not usually done?

Comment: $H(X|Y )$ is not a random variable, it is constant .

Comment: Yes, which is similar to the classical definition of conditional expectation. However you see how it could instead be defined similar to the modern definition of conditional expectation, and thus be a random variable?

Comment: @ThomasAhle: It sure makes sense to define the entropy of the conditional distribution of a random variable, which would be a random variable (depending on the condition), and sometimes it is helpful to work with that.  However, the usual conditional entropy (a number) is more commonly used (because of its miraculous consistency with intuition), and that's why the notation $H(X|Y)$ is used for this more common usage than the less common usage.

Comment: @ThomasAhle: You are absolutely right: $H(X|Y=Y)$ is a random variable (whereas $H(X|Y=y)$ is a number, namely, the entropy of the conditional distribution $p_{X|Y=y}$). In some older textbooks you even see the more accurate notation $EH(X|Y)$ for what is now often abbreviated as $H(X|Y)$.

Comment: @Bernhard Can you post this comment as an answer?